# How to change state of an entity which multiple objects are referring to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an object named "SPs" referring to list of stock products from all providers stored in db.

In my action I need to create a new object named "PSPs" which filters SPs based on current provider's ID:

```
Public ActionResult Edit(int id, int pid)
{
   var SPs = dbContext.Products.Where(o => o.ID == id).Select(o => o.SPs).ToList();
   // do something based on SPs
   ...
   var PSPs = Filter(SPs, pid);
   // edit all PSPs
```

I tried to **change the state of entities** referred by PSPs like this:

```
    PSPs.ForEach(o => { 
       dbContext.Entry(o).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

but received an exception with message like this:

> Attaching an entity of type 'SP' failed because another entity of the
>   same type already has the same primary key value.

for more, here is SPs navigation property in Product class:

```
public ICollection<SP> SPs { get; set; }
```

and SP class:

```
public class StockProduct
{
     [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int SPID { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Product")]
     public int ProductID { get; set; }
     public Product Product { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Provider")]
     public int ProviderID { get; set; }
     public Provider Provider { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

So, any idea?

Comment: I think that in your table there is a unique constraint on your State field.

Comment: Can we see your Product class pls ?

Comment: @GGO: isn't it the `SP` class we should look at?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @CoskunOzogul: State is not a property of the object itself, but of the DbSet entry inside the DbContext. It is not mapped to a Db column and therefore can't have a unique constraint. Regarding the question at hand: I believe the error comes from another code piece that what is shown. The .Entry() call attaches the object, if it is not in the context before the call; however, from the code pieces this is to be expected. If you create new PSP objects, make sure the navigation property back to SP is null (you can set the FK though) before attaching it to the context.

Comment: @Flater more info added

Comment: @CoskunOzogul: as I said PSPs = Filter(SPs, pid), while Filter returns a result of type List<SP>. In different scenarios I want to change state of PSPs to modified, detached, deleted, and added.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out from the exception that you have another instance of `SP` in `ChangeTracker`. You need to detach the other instance then you can attach new one.

The exception is descriptive itself : **You can not attach entities with duplicate `Primary Keys`.**